# How can I solve below flutter error in android studio 3.5

Tags: flutter, dart

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\stop\android\app\build.gradle' line: 5

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'reader' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
  Command: C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\stop\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Info:-**

1.I have deleted IOS directory before running  build apk

2.I don't know if IOS directory affect a flutter app or not

3.After trying to build apk this above error is displaying in the console box

I have added **build.gradle** code

```
//buildscript {
//    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
//    repositories {
//        google()
//        jcenter()
//    }

    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        }
    }







    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Local.properties**

```
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\Users\\user\\flutter
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
flutter.buildMode=release
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.ramram.quit"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I have added build.grale and local properties please help now...

Below code is the latest error

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\stop\android\build.gradle' line: 30

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 15s
  Command: C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\stop\android\gradlew.bat app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Comment: Paste your gradle file here. Looks like a compilation error caused by some unwanted code.

Comment: i have added rest of codes please have a look at the original question

Comment: I have deleted IOS directory.